# tinymce unable to show icon "Insertfile" on Toolbar

Tags: javascript, insert, tinymce

just installed system, and for some reason cannot get the insert file icon to load on the toolbar.

The code is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
plugins: [
"advlist autolink lists link image charmap print hr anchor pagebreak searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
],
theme: "modern",
image_advtab: true,
toolbar: " undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons insertfile "

})
</script>
```

All of the other icons show up but the insertfile does not.

Any suggestions would be appreciated…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add plugin `moxiemanager` and toolbar `insertfile` in your editor initilization:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "moxiemanager link image",
  external_plugins: {
        "moxiemanager": "https://www.moxiemanager.com/moxiemanager/plugin.min.js"
    },
    toolbar: "insertfile link image",
    menubar: false,
    moxiemanager_file_settings : {
        /* Only list txt files, and remove side navigation. */
        moxiemanager_extensions : 'txt',
        moxiemanager_leftpanel : false
    },
    moxiemanager_image_settings : {
        /* Scope to different folder, show thumbnails of selected extensions */
        moxiemanager_title : 'Images',
        moxiemanager_extensions : 'jpg,png,gif',
        moxiemanager_rootpath : '/testfiles/testfolder',
        moxiemanager_view : 'thumbs'
    }
});
```

It will add a new button that will give you the opportunity to insert many types of files.

You can test and check results in here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvVOZg

Comment: Please post a Tinymce jsfiddle so we can help you

Comment: `insert` not `insertfile`

Answer (score 0):

[this is an example,but it not show "insert file" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuixt.png)